# Python JSON module not throwing exception for invalid JSON

Tags: python, json

So, valid JSON must be an Object or Array, correct?  I was expecting the following code to throw an exception but it is not:

```
>>> import json
>>> json.loads("245235")
245235
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's not invalid JSON*. Number is a valid JSON type, just like object. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Data_types.2C_syntax_and_example any of these types could appear on its own, albeit that object and array are probably the most common top level types.

*according to the python implementation

EDIT:

As pointed out in a deleted (not sure why) answer, the python docs suggest that the JSON RFC does require the top level object to be of array or object type, but that the `json` module doesn't enforce this.  Since a lot of what I know about JSON has come from working with the python `json` module, I don't know how portable this behavior is.

As requested, this is noted at http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#standard-compliance:

> This module does not comply with the RFC in a strict fashion,
>   implementing some extensions that are valid JavaScript but not valid
>   JSON. In particular:
>
> - Top-level non-object, non-array values are accepted and output;
> - Infinite and NaN number values are accepted and output;
> - Repeated names within an object are accepted, and only the value of the last name-value pair is used.

Comment: The RFC only applies to the `application/json` media type, which is only a subset of possible use-cases for JSON.

Comment: Gotcha, so should I check for isinstance(result, dict) (or list) if I'm trying to validate application/json data.

Comment: @speg: Yeah that sounds reasonable. I briefly poked around in the docs to see if you can ask it to be strict about this, but I don't see any obvious way to do that, so checking for the extensions you don't want seems fair.

Answer (score 2):

JSON data can have a [wide range of types](http://json.org/) including strings, numbers and booleans